# Foundation Orbit bullets not centering when using show-for-small

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit, bulletedlist

I would like to have some kind of navigation for a slider when viewed on a mobile device. Since the directional arrows won't show on mobile (if anyone can tell how to make them, that would be awesome) I thought a good solution would be to have a different slider, same images, that is "show-for-small" and has bullets underneath.

It works, but there is an issue that's killing me. If you load the page with the browser window wide (desktop) and scale to a mobile width the sliders switch, but the bullets aren't centered. They appear shifted to the right. If you reload the page at that mobile width with they are fine, perfectly centered below the image.

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this? I set up a page to demonstrate the problem. www.jonesco.com/_foundation/bullet_problem.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.orbit-bullets {
    display: table;
    text-align: center; 
}
```